# Navigator: cannot find a generator/route for pushNamed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change screens using the value of a string inside a json object but I get the following error in the console and it does not change my screen:

> Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings ("alert", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.
>
> Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
>
> 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
> 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
> 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
> 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
>
> Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

This is my Home Page, the method is working until Navigator.pushNamed(context, opt['ruta']);:

```
 List<Widget> _listItems(List<dynamic> data, BuildContext context) {

    final List<Widget> options = [];

    data.forEach((opt){
      final widgetTemp = ListTile(
        title: Text(opt['texto']),
        leading: getIcon(opt['icon']),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.blue,),
        onTap: (){
          print("Hello");

          Navigator.pushNamed(context, opt['ruta']);

        },
      );

      options..add(widgetTemp)
             ..add(Divider());
    });
return options;
  }
```

And this is my main.dart where I have the routes:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Components App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{

          '/' : (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
          '/alert' : (BuildContext context) => AlertPage(),
          '/avatar' : (BuildContext context) => AvatarPage(),
      },

      onGenerateRoute: (settings){
        print("Ruta llamada: ${settings.name }");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the leading `/`:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/${opt['ruta']}');
```

The route name needs to match the generators **exactly**.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this kind of errors always write your route names in a separated file like constants of something. That way you sure that every route name used in pushNamed is equal to what onGenerateRoute has.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer right now is:

```
Navigator.of(context,
              rootNavigator: true).pushNamed('/${element['ruta']}');
```